# Nunmpy sum() function + comprehensions: int32 or in64?

Tags: python, numpy, types

Why does the numpy.sum and numpy.prod function return int32 when the input is a list of int, and int64 if it's a generator for the same list? What's the best way to coerce them to use int64 when operating on a list?

E.g.

```
sum([x for x in range(800000)]) == -2122947200
sum((x for x in range(800000))) == 319999600000L
```

Python 2.7

Comment: I can't reproduce ...

Comment: I get 319999600000L for both.

Comment: Same, I get `319999600000` for both. Are you on 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: For the same code in Python 3 I get the latter result. This is on my phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are likely using `numpy.sum` instead of the built-in `sum`, a side effect of `from numy import *`. Be advised not to do so, as it will cause no end of confusion. Instead, use something like `import numpy as np`, and refer to the numpy namespace with the short `np` prefix.

To answer your question, `numpy.sum` makes the accumulator type the same as the type of the array. On a 32-bit system, numpy coerces the list into an int32 array, which causes `numpy.sum` to use a 32-bit accumulator. When given a generator expression, `numpy.sum` falls back to calling `sum`, which promotes integers to longs. To force the use of a 64-bit accumulator for array/list input, use the `dtype` parameter:

```
>>> np.sum([x for x in range(800000)], dtype=np.int64)
319999600000
```

Comment: Incidentally, the documentation for `numpy.sum` makes no mention of working for generators; the documentation requires an array-like input. However, the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.8.1/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L1621) has a weird special case for generators (and not other iterators or iterables) that uses the Python built-in sum.

Comment: Aha that caught me out! I'm using iPython Notebook which appears to `from numpy import *` on startup.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for pointing out that `numpy.sum` falls back to the built-in `sum` when given a generator. This is not a mere curiosity, it exposes a flaw in my answer. I've now it the answer to specify that `dtype` should be used with array/list input, not with any kind of input. (When the input is a generator, the `dtype` keyword argument is ignored, which is presumably a bug in `numpy.sum`.)

Comment: @Bicubic I believe this is a bug in iPython Notebook and should be reported to its maintainers. Clobbering built-in functions like `sum` is *evil*. Importing numpy with `import numpy as np` is established practice.

Comment: `ipython --pylab` loads `numpy` both as `*` and `np`.

Comment: @hpaulj This would still clobber builtins `sum`, `all`, and `any`. It also confuses beginners as to what primitives come from numpy and what from Python proper. While that is convenient in the short term for the purpose of placing the scientific user in a Matlab-like environment, it is a disservice in the long run.

Comment: `ipython --pylab --TerminalIPythonApp.pylab_import_all=False` turns off the `*` import.