# Python: Why is `np.sum([x for x in c]) != np.sum(x for x in c)`

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the following code

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2])
b = np.array([3,4])
c = [a,b]
np.sum(x for x in c) # array([4,6])
np.sum(c) # 10
```

What is the rationale behind treating lists different from generator expressions?

Comment: This question just needs a little knowledge about `np.sum` and generator expressions. Also the question *What is the rationale behind treating lists different from generator expressions?* means that OP is miss understanding the behavior of the `np.sum` here.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25357326/nunmpy-sum-function-comprehensions-int32-or-in64/25357479#25357479

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
>>> np.sum(x for x in c)
array([4, 6])
```

is equivalent to summing over the fist dimension:

```
>>> np.sum(c, axis=0)
array([4, 6])
```

On the other hand, his will sum over all dimensions:

```
>>> np.sum(c)
10
```

Relevant part of the documentation:

> `np.sum(a, axis=None, ...`
>
> Sum of array elements over a given axis.
> `axis=None`, will sum all of the elements of the input array.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from this pull request https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/10670

> I think the original rationale for this change was to allow the following change to not break this code
>
> ```
> from numpy import *
>
> def my_func(n):
>     return sum(i*i for i in range(n))
> ```
>
> Reasons to deprecate it:
>
> - sum is the only function to do this, even though any and all also shadow builtins
> - It's not documented
> - It's not consistent with np.array(generator).sum(), which already fails.

Answer (score 0):

Generator expression yields or generates one element at a time.
Since `c` has arrays `a` and `b` as its elements, it will apply sum to individual arrays during `np.sum(x for x in c)`.

np.sum() sums up all the elements of c after flattening them.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you have the difference is that you are iterating an array of arrays instead of separate elements in the first case. I guess the rational explanation is that `numpy` doesn't know in advance what is yielded from generator and sums each element separately. And, the later statement treats your array of arrays as matrix and sums all its elements by default because they all are known in advance.

You can achieve the same result with:

```
assert np.sum(c, axis=0).tolist() == [4, 6]
```

Otherwise, you can try:

```
from itertools import chain
assert np.sum(list(chain(*c))) == 10
```

Answer (score 0):

In numpy 1.13.3, `numpy.sum()` uses Python's build-in `sum()` to sum up the elements of a generator one by one. For array-likes (e.g., lists and arrays), numpy's vectorized implementation of `sum()` (which by default flattens the array-like and sums up its elements) is used.

My guess about the rational: The idea behind generators is that the elements are taken and *processed one by one.* The idea behind vectorization is that all data is ideally taken at once and *processed in parallel.* So, the ideas are complete opposites of each other.

Now, if a user explicitly provides a generator as an argument to `numpy.sum()` thent she explicitly wants the generated elements (vectors [1, 2] and [3, 4] in your example) to be summed up one by one and, therefore, do not wants the vectorization.

If a user provides an array-like as an argument to `numpy.sum()` then it is assumed that she wants the vectorized version of `sum()` to be applied. The questions is only what the primitive elements of the array-like that should be summed up are. By default, the array-like is flattened and the values of the flattened array-like (1, 2, 3, and 4 in your example) are summed up. This behavior can be changed using the `axis` parameter.

That is why generators are processed differently from arrays.